# How to get mean of in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a an average based on dates. For that I am using this code:

```
new_data = df_available.groupby('vin')['newTime'].agg(['min','max'])
```

And it gives me a result like:

```
                                      min                     max
vin                                                              
2T2BZMCA9GC490580              2021-03-23 13:11:49.026 2021-03-23 13:51:28.668
2T2BZMCA9GC490581              2021-03-23 13:11:50.199 2021-03-23 13:51:29.714
2T2BZMCA9GC490582              2021-03-23 13:11:51.268 2021-03-23 13:51:30.753
2T2BZMCA9GC490583              2021-03-23 13:11:52.308 2021-03-23 13:51:31.789
2T2BZMCA9GC490584              2021-03-23 13:11:53.441 2021-03-23 13:51:33.367
```

And I am calculating the mean using:

```
round(((new_data['max'] - new_data['min']).dt.total_seconds() / 3600 / 24).mean(),4)
```

Is this the right way to calculate the mean in this formula? Will it calculate each row and create a mean or do I need to create some loop?

Comment: What do you mean by taking 'mean' here ?   Seems like you are calculating the time difference in unit of days.

Comment: I am trying to create mean of max-min in each row. r1 = 5,r2 = 6 ... then r.mean(). The code which I shared above will it calculate each row or aggregate.

Comment: It's look alright to me.  You can break it down into small steps (e.g. just `(new_data['max'] - new_data['min'])` ) and verify the calculation result.

Comment: are you still stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'mean' to your agg.

Comment: But I need altered values

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have this sample data:

```
data = {'index': ['2014-06-22 10:46:00', '2014-06-24 19:52:00', '2014-06-25 17:02:00', '2014-06-25 17:55:00', '2014-07-02 11:36:00', '2014-07-06 12:40:00', '2014-07-05 12:46:00', '2014-07-27 15:12:00'],
    'type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C'],
    'sum_col': [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['index', 'type', 'sum_col'])
df['index'] = pd.to_datetime(df['index'])
df = df.set_index('index')
df['weekofyear'] = df.index.weekofyear
df['date'] = df.index
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

You can write like this:

```
round(df.groupby(['type'])[['date']].transform(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).total_seconds()/ 3600 / 24).mean(), 4)
```

---

```
date    18.7915
dtype: float64
```

You are basically calculating the days. So you can use this also:

```
round(df.groupby(['type'])[['date']].transform(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).days).mean(), 4)
```

---

```
date    18.25
dtype: float64
```

But the output would be a bit different in terms of decimal values.